# How to read in parallel multiple chunks from the same connection in R?

Tags: r, optimization, parallel-processing

I have a .bz2 file and I want to read it and do some processing. The file cannot be loaded in memory. I want to do some computations on the chunks I read and I they can be performed independently of one another and therefore I thought I would try to do it in parallel.
I tried the following:

```
library(parallel)
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
con = file("myfile.bz2", "r")


parLapply(cl, con,
          function(x)
            print(head(read.csv(x, nrows = 100, stringsAsFactors = F, header = F, colClasses = "character", fill = F), 16)))
## Doesn't work Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  one node produced an error: 'file' must be a character string or connection

parLapply(cl, list(con, con, con),
          function(x)
            print(head(read.csv(x, nrows = 100, stringsAsFactors = F, header = F, colClasses = "character", fill = F), 16)))
## Doesn't work Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: invalid connection
```

Can this somehow work?
Also any other recommendation as to how to go about it would be really helpful, as I am new to the world of parallel processing.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot and **must not** use connections from one R process in another R process - connections are unique to the R session where they are created.

Internally, they are just integer indices and there is very little in R that protects you from mistakenly trying to use them in other R processes.  If your want to know for details, see https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/Wishlist-for-R/issues/81.

FWIW, if you use the [**future**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) framework for parallelization and set R option `future.globals.onReference` to `"error"`, then it protects you against this mistake (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-non-exportable-objects.html).  For example,

```r
library(future.apply)
options(future.globals.onReference = "error")

library(parallel)
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

cat("Hello world\n", file = bzfile("myfile.bz2", open="wb"))
con <- file("myfile.bz2", "r")

y <- future_lapply(list(con, con, con), FUN = function(x) {
  data <- read.csv(x, nrows = 100, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = FALSE, colClasses = "character", fill = FALSE)
  print(head(data), 16)
})
Error: Detected a non-exportable reference ('externalptr') in one of the globals (<unknown>) used in the future expression
```

Comment: That was really informative, thank you! Do you think there is a way to do what I want somehow (I mean the read chunks in parallel from the same file part)?

Comment: Open the file on each workers and then use the `skip` argument of `read.csv()` to skip into the file.  Yes, `read.csv()` will have to read the file from the beginning when it's skipping, but at least it only has to look for newlines - it won't spend time parsing the fields.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please add some sample code for this in your answer?